# MVC MaxJsonLength error returning a view

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

i'm getting an error when I return a View in MVC. this error is **Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer**.
I already set the MaxJsonLength property in my webconfig and the error is still there.

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

I see a lot of answers in another questions, but the solution i saw is that you can return a JsonResult and at this point change the MaxJsonLength in the variable. but the problem is that im returning a View, and i can't find an answer to this.

I'm using MVC3 with framework 4.5.2. the controller consults the data from another project in solution where i have my business logic, its just a library project.

Comment: are you serializing the model in the View?

Comment: What line throws the error?  Where is serialization or deserialization actually taking place?  If you're returning a view then how is JSON involved at all?

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with exceeding the max length when using the EntityFramework.  An entity creates a circular loop via it's navigation props which can cause an overflow condition when serializing into JSON with the default serializer.  You can try setting max depth, a different serializer, changing the EF proxy/ll settings, etc.

Maybe something in your view is causing a similar issue?  If this is the case with you there are a lot of solutions covered in other posts on SO, check 'em out.